# add calendar event without opening calendar

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-calendar

In my app, the user can set up to 3 reminders for a task, but every time I press the "set reminder" button it opens up the calendar app. Is there any way to set the calendar events without opening the default calendar app? I just want to add an event without starting the calendar activity.

This is what my code looks like now:

```
Calendar beginTime = Calendar.getInstance();
beginTime.set(2013, Calendar.MAY, 10, 3, 00);
startMillis = beginTime.getTimeInMillis();
Calendar endTime = Calendar.getInstance();
endTime.set(2012, Calendar.MAY, 10, 4, 00);
endMillis = endTime.getTimeInMillis();

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT);
intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
intent.putExtra(Events.TITLE, "Test Android");
intent.putExtra(Events.EVENT_LOCATION, "Test Location");
intent.putExtra(Events.DESCRIPTION, "Test Description Examples");

intent.putExtra(Events.DTSTART, startMillis);
intent.putExtra(Events.DTEND, endMillis);
intent.putExtra(Events.ALL_DAY, false);
intent.putExtra(Events.EVENT_END_TIMEZONE, "Europe/London");


intent.putExtra(Events.ACCESS_LEVEL, Events.ACCESS_PRIVATE);
intent.putExtra(Events.AVAILABILITY, Events.AVAILABILITY_BUSY);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This will look something like this:

```
    final ContentValues event = new ContentValues();
    event.put(Events.CALENDAR_ID, 1);

    event.put(Events.TITLE, title);
    event.put(Events.DESCRIPTION, description);
    event.put(Events.EVENT_LOCATION, location);

    event.put(Events.DTSTART, startTimeMillis);
    event.put(Events.DTEND, endTimeMillis);
    event.put(Events.ALL_DAY, 0);   // 0 for false, 1 for true
    event.put(Events.HAS_ALARM, 1); // 0 for false, 1 for true

    String timeZone = TimeZone.getDefault().getID();
    event.put(Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, timeZone);

    Uri baseUri;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 8) {
        baseUri = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events");
    } else {
        baseUri = Uri.parse("content://calendar/events");
    }

    context.getContentResolver().insert(baseUri, event);
```

Comment: firstly what is PandoraUtil?? and secondly very last line of your code says activity.getCon..... do i have to create a new activity or this this should be this.getContentResolver???? thanks.... cant find anything called PandoraUtil... which package is it belong to... or is it deprecated? btw i'm not using an emulator, my device is nexus 7 with running android 4.2.2

Comment: Sorry, accidentally included a private utility. I've updated the example to be a bit clearer. You can use any context to call getContentResolver(). If this is called from within an activity, it's simplest to just use the activity itself for the context. Otherwise you should generally use the Application context (context.getApplicationContext()).

Comment: @dhaag23: i am using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11586054/android-insert-calendar-intent-without-alarm-reminder code for doing same. where it is working good on below 4.0 (ICS). but above 4.0 it's not working. any suggestion? i tried for very long time

Comment: Complementing dhaag23's answer, you could use event.put(Events.DTSTART, startMillis); rather than use as string.

Comment: Thanks KVISH for editing the answer to use the constants in CalendarContract.Events static inner class. At the time I wrote this answer, these were not yet publicly available.

Comment: It doesn't add the event to calander on android 5, any help?