# Alarm for all the dates in SQL table in android

Tags: android, android-sqlite, alarmmanager, android-notifications

First time I am trying to do something with alarm/notifications in my app.

I have dates in my SQL Database and I want to trigger notification on all those dates.

People might find this as a duplicate, Sorry for that but all the questions I came across till now had half written code along . It was difficult to understand.

After referring so many questions and tuts now am confused from where to start with.

So, please can anyone help how should I move on from here. I have all the dates in table in the string format.

Answer (score 0):

Simple

Provided that you know how to query these dates (if not please say so and i'll update my answer accordingly) you can do one of the following:

1. Add your events to the Google Calendar programmatically and allow the predefined Google account and its notifications preferences do the work for you (example on how is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16473537/add-calendar-event-without-opening-calendar)).
2. Schedule you own alarm events and when these are called show your own UX (example for a lead to start from [here](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html)).

Goodluck.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i am about to refer those links now ! ya , i know how to query those dates no issues with database . thanks. i will update after refering the links.